# How to start application in specific workspace programmatically on GNOME 3

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, window

I'd like to write bash script that starts certain application on startup. I would like to have for example Firefox opened in first workspace, Slack on second, spotify on third. I know how to start these applications, but don't know how to place them in specific workspace. Is it possible in Ubuntu 17 with GNOME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly a "*programmatic*" solution, but you may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Auto Move Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/) to achieve your goal (assuming you meant Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME shell). This extension lets you

> Move applications to specific workspaces when they create windows.

Once the extension is installed and activated, open its settings and click on "**Add Rule**" to select an application and a workspace for the application.

[image]